# Finding triplets code fails in debugging its throwing garbage value

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I Have written a test script to find triplets in python list
such that in a list if sum of any two items & there sum exist in list as item of list
it has to note that pair to be triplets
now my task is count how many triplets does exist in list
for more about this problem explanation you can refer [here](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/count-the-triplets4615/1)

now it can be done easily with two loops(O(n^2)) approach but in order to bring the time complexity close O(n) i.e. traversing items of list only n time
where n is no. of element list has

`Mine Approach is`:

i am using a while loop i is to go from 0 to n while j will go from i+1 to n
if j which referencing second element index cross to n(last element) only then updation
of i is done so now i can skip current element as is go no triplet and now lookout for
i+1 to n while j is already i+1 making it j always in lead j=i+1

`Respective python code for Approach Is:`

```
def check(A,n):
 i=0
 j=i+1
 count=0
 while i<n:
  if j==n:
   i+=1
   j=i+1
  temp=A[i]+A[j]
  if temp in A:
   count+=1
   j+=1  #updation for not going to same loop secondth time
  else:
   j+=1
 return count 

def main():
 A=[]
 n=int(input('Define length:'))
 for a in range(0,n):
  x=int(input('Array[{}]'.format(a)))
  A.append(x)

 c=check(A,n)
 print(c)



main()
```

The Approach is good but the code doesn't work its just lagging in order to solve it i debugged the code[here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_debugger)
and found the `count` variable ended up in returning garbage value
[local-variable-debugged-output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uThHl.png) & [full-o/p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYsME.png)

`Note:(Optional)` The original question was lacking at getting the correct value of `Count` ,count variable is returning in form of garbage collection(You can checkout from the pictures of debugging o/p posted) After getting a Suggestion From User @PeterdeRivaz
it get cleared that as loop was running we are not updating i index to move forward and ended up in never ending situation as i was only about to update when j becomes == n i.e. last index(for comparision of all pairs) and also not other condition is getting true
so from suggestion i update j+=1 to both condition even if it fail & even if it pass these way traversal is sure
then after i was at problem of getting out of index which solution is posted by me where i was laging but the real solver of this problem is @PeterdeRivaz A Huge shoutout to you i know giving credits in post
could be viloted code of honour i am not sure
but i write this note so that other memebers can understand what problem was and what it became so on the basis of it i posted this answer.

Comment: `set()` is the way to go here - because the membership check is O(1).  Just check if a+b  (the sum) is in this Set.

Comment: @DanielHao In Debugging I Am seeing `count` is returning true result of my answer but the only problem is it going out of index as a typeerror in case of `list`  i tried reducing last reference to n-1 as indexing going from 0 to n-1 but in both attempt the list is getting out of index

Comment: @DanielHao and if i converting to `Set` the typeerror is set object doesn't support indexing which is true cause set is unordered data structures there is no fixed place for every item in a set

Comment: @DanielHao Also O(nlogn) soution can be valid but no valid for O(n^2) which your solution was and please don't delete your previous answer when you can edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally with lots of Debugging Sessions I Finally Get To know where My Code was lagging at
during the last few iteration when j was at last index and i at second last index `condition j==n`become:`n==n` then i got updated to last index while j crosses more than that of last index(See Below)

```
if j==n:
 i+=1
 j=i+1
```

can't handle anymore iteration as i already becomes last element & by `j=i+1`
goes out of index
due to which next statement  `temp=A[i]+A[j]` is executed and as j index is not present in list it throws error
in order to solve it i just have to tolerate this special case when j was encounter to be last index but due to list traversal logic`i+=1,j=i+1`(the only updation of i)j index is updated to index which is not present in array`A`
as a result i created a nested if to double check if above condition is encounter when it does the only thing i need to is get out of loop using `break`

```
if j==n:
 i+=1
 j=i+1
 if j==n:
  break
```

by this small improvement the code now running perfectly fine
here is a full code snippet

```
def check(A,n):
 i=0
 j=int(i+1)
 n=int(n)
 count=0
 
 while i<n:  
  if j==n:
   i+=1
   j=i+1
   if j==n:
       break
   
  temp=A[i]+A[j]
  if temp in A:
   count+=1
   j+=1
  else:
   j+=1
 return count 

def main():
 A=[]
 n=int(input('Define length:'))
 for a in range(0,n):
  x=int(input('Array[{}]'.format(a)))
  A.append(x)
 c=check(A,n)
 print(c)



main()
```

it is working quite good and please do let me know if this code fail any exceptional case

`Note:`
And those of members who are suggesting ,saying convert `list` to `Set` to bring time complexity to `O(1)` well i do actually tried this but as `Set` Data Structures Is unordered DS so when accessing it with index values `i,j`
it throws error Which is obvious so if you know how to do it post a answer below but the answer is still limeted to approach with `O(n)` even in the worst case it should be `O(nlog n)` but `O(n^2)` is not acceptable

Answer (score 1):

If you find a solution, i.e. `temp in A` is true, then you will increment count, but not change either loop variable i or j.  This means that the loop will repeat on the next iteration at exactly the same locations so no progress will be made.

I suggest changing the code such that the `j+=1` is not in the else branch, but always happens.

By the way, you should probably convert A into a set `B=set(A)` in order to accelerate the  `temp in A` test.

Comment: Good Suggestion an updation of j to j+=1 as a win-win condition for both But for converting list to test i am getting a typerror as set object does not support indexing

Comment: If you got this then post code snippet so we can see this in action @PeterdeRivaz